# Iterating through the rows a dataframe and changing the value of one column based on another

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, google-translate

I can't seem to find an answer here. I have a dataframe that has 800k rows. I want to iterate over each row, pass the value of a string in one column to the Google Translate API and then add the translation to another column in that row. When I do it this way it only gives me the values from the first row for the whole dataframe (`df$word`, and `df$heading`) and reproduces it in every row after. What I want is to get the value of `$word` in row 1, I want to translate it with the API and make that translation the value of `$fr_translation` in row 1. I want to do this for each individual row. I am sure it is something easy but I am pretty new to R. Here is the code that works for the translation but not for each individual row:

```
library(translate)
set.key("my_key")

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
  df$fr_translation <- translate(df$word, 'en', 'fr')
  df$fr_heading <- translate(df$heading, 'en', 'fr')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not referencing the `i`th row at each iteration. Fix the part inside the loop to be like this:

```
  df$fr_translation[i] <- translate(df$word[i], 'en', 'fr')
  df$fr_heading[i] <- translate(df$heading[i], 'en', 'fr')
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, knew it was something simple. Much appreciated

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other response solved your issue, please mark as accepted.